# Why should we HAVING clause in SQL should followed by GROUP BY and preceded ORDER BY statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 5
ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) DESC;
```

Why should i follow this syntax ?

Comment: You should follow this syntax because any other order would likely result in your query not even compiling.

Comment: If not like this, how do you want to do it instead?

Comment: *Why should i follow this syntax ?* Because the server will not understand the syntax that you will come up with for it. He has his own, and that's enough for him.

Comment: Nevertheless you have some degree of freedom. You may use output field name (if you'd specify it) or its positional number (which is 1) in HAVING and ORDER BY instead of duplicate its expression.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is it not working? If it is working, why are you asking this question?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) as cnt1, Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
HAVING cnt1 > 5
ORDER BY cnt1 DESC;

Comment: The query won't work if you don't. All languages have syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is because HAVING is used for aggregate functions and MySQL does not know what to group the function on in order to find the aggregation for the clause; so the GROUP BY needs to come before but the order can be done after the query has generated the results.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING works just like the WHERE clause and is made to filter out the result after the GROUP BY has been made. So basically you are just doing a WHERE on the GROUP BY. Then finally MySql will perform the ORDER BY on the final resultset to provide you with an ordered resultset.

To have more info you can have a look at Visual Explain Plan. That's how the sql engine executes the query and will help you optimize your sql queries.

I hope it provides you a better understanding of how they works.